# Uncaught Error: Invalid row type for row 0

Tags: python, json, google-visualization

I am trying to create an intensity map of US using the google api. I am fetching data in python from a publicly available dataset and then passing it on to the UI side. Here is the code for it

```
query_string = 'SELECT state, count(*) FROM [{0}] GROUP by state;'.format(_DATABASE_NAME)
births = self.run_query(query_string, filename='data/states.json')
rows = births[u'rows']
states = []
for row in rows:
   name = row[u'f'][0][u'v']
   num = row[u'f'][1][u'v']
   if name == None: name = u'None'
       state = {'state':unicode.encode(name), 'total':int(num)}
       states = states + [state]
states.insert(0, ('State','No of users'))
logging.info(json.encode(states))
context = {"states": json.encode(states)}
self.render_response('index.html', context)
```

This is how the json.encode(states) looks like -

```
[["State","No of users"],{"state":"AL","total":1957392},{"state":"AK","total":324183},{"state":"AZ","total":1837630},{"state":"AR","total":1062588},{"state":"CA","total":13794114},...........
```

And here is the index.html file -

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
   google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geomap']});
   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

    function drawMap() {
        console.log("In draw map function");
      var test = {{states|safe}};
      console.log(test);  console.log(test);
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable({{states|safe}});

      var options = {};
      options['region'] = 'US'
      options['dataMode'] = 'regions';

      var container = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
      var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(container);
      geomap.draw(data, options);
  };
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='map_canvas'></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Why am I getting this kind of an error? I am seeing the following in the browser console - 
Uncaught Error: Invalid row type for row 0 
lda
Tp
drawMap  (index:12)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is `json.encode`?  Usually, one would use `json.dumps` or something similar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

generally speaking, `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable` expects an array of arrays (list of lists in python).  You've got a bunch of `dict` in your list which I don't think should be there.

You probably should have:

```
state = [unicode.encode(name), int(num)]
states.append(state)  # this is better than states = states + [state]
```